# Pie Chart в виде бублика

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, xcode

Добрый день. Есть задачка сделать Pie Chart

Найти в инете хороший гайд и сделать все мне удалось, кроме одного. Но мне нужно сделать ее в виде бублика. Можно было бы сверху положить лейбл и закруглить его если б эта диаграмма не была бы подвижной!

Суть вопроса изображена на картинке ниже. Как мне из полностью залитого круга сделать бублик.

Благодарен буду за любую информацию! Заранее спасибо!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866179/draw-segments-from-a-circle-or-donut

Answer (score 0):

Можно положить на полностью залитый круг картинку в форме круга меньшего размера и будем Вам бублик. Для iOS есть open source framework CorePlot который содержит PieChart

Comment: Это было б супер, если если бы этот бублик не двигался. Но по факту получалось, что оно вытягивалось из под фона и смотрелось как-то криво...